# Send mail through microsoft exchange server using asp .net

Tags: asp.net, .net

I want to send mails through the application developed in asp .net..using System.web.mail, i have written the code which is working at one place. But when I am trying the same at my company it shows error that "system does not have rights to submit mail to the server"

I have used the cdo object.

Mailmsg.Fields.Add("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpauthenticate", "1");    //basic authentication

Please help me resolve..this

Answer (score 1):

The most likely cause of this issue is that the user identity that is being used for the ASP.Net application pool which will almost certainly be a user specific to the machine that IIS is running on (such as LocalService, LocalSystem, NetworkService, or ApplicationPoolIdentity) is not known by the Exchange Server which is likely running on a different machine.

There are different ways to resolve this depending on how much control you have over each server.

1) You can create a new application pool using a domain user with authority to send exchange email as the identity and then move your ASP.Net application to that pool.

2) You can add/configure the SMTP service on the IIS machine to relay messages to the Exchange server, then just save your generated emails into the local pickup directory. This is my preferred option so that IIS doesn't get hung up trying to resolve addresses and to ensure that the mail is delivered at some point in the future if Exchange server is down for some reason (maintenance, network failure, etc).